# Can I use Contact Form DB plugin in my wordpress site for saving and displaying data without sending emails

Tags: database, wordpress, customization, contact-form-7

I want to create a wordpress custom plugin for saving three fields of data and also an image of the same from wp-admin area for every item. It should be able to display all these items in a page.
When I searched for a plugin I found Contact Form DB plugin which can be used as contact form 7 plugin extension for saving data send through it..
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/

Can I use Contact Form DB plugin in my wordpress site for saving and displaying data without sending emails? It also sends email but I only want to store and display data.

Another problem:- I'm already using a contact form from contact form 7 plugin for sending email enquiries.. Will the changes for saving data in contact form 7 affect its working?

Please help me with any reference or solution as I'm new to wordpress and currently don't know about plugin development.
Any help will be greatly appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup the Contact form 7 and put in a junk or noreply email address to send the message to on Contact form 7 it will still log the message being sent in the contact form DB

So in the shortcode template send message to junk@yourdomain.com and whenever a user submits it will try to send to that email and will still log the email as being sent.  Personally I would actually create that email address so that your smtp doesn't get flooded with bounce back from smtp server.

Comment: Hi.., Thanks a lot for the help.. :-)  Surely I will try this.. Is there any alternative option known to you for doing this ? I mean for saving and displaying custom data/image etc in normal pages or post? Thank you.

Comment: I feel that this question is something completely different.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply... I need a plugin which can be used for storing and displaying some additional data and an image with each post/page.. But I'm not sure if there is a plugin for my requirement.  Anyway thanks a lot.. Your answer is correct for my above question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action hook to prevent form being sent to email..
(I have tested this with "Contact Form DB" plugin - it saves data before email is filtered)

To filter only specific Form IDs - use something like this:

```
function wpcf7_skip_email_sending($wpcf7_data)
{
    if ( in_array($wpcf7_data->id(), array(2,3,7)) ) {
        $wpcf7_data->skip_mail = true;
    }
}
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_skip_email_sending");
```

(For older CF7 version you might have to change `$wpcf7_data->id()` to `$wpcf7_data->id`)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid sending emails, without even touching the files, the fastest way is to add in the [additional settings](https://contactform7.com/additional-settings/) tab

```
demo_mode: on
```

or

```
skip_mail: on
```

With Contact Form DB both works fine. The difference is that `demo_mode` won't work with Flamingo.